# Julia MethodError for y=1/x

Tags: julia

I am absolute Newbie, try to plot y=1/x for x=(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0) coming out with MethodError: no method matching /(::Int64, ::NTuple{10,Float64})

I have try y=x^(-1) seem like coming out with same result, documentation didn't help....or I can't find the right one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to apply the operation element wise you need to use broadcasting in Julia, e.g. with "dot-notation":

```
julia> x=(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)
(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)

julia> y = 1 ./ x
(1.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333, 0.25, 0.2)
```

See https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Broadcasting-1